# Integrating Commerce Feeds and Physical Field. (Drupal Commerce)

Tags: commerce

I'm importing over 40K of products from a .csv file.  The file includes weights and dimensions (height,width,length).  I use physical field module to define my fields for weight and dimension. I'm having problem mapping weights and dimensions from my .csv file to my product table where I define the weights and dimensions as Physical Field (Physical Field Module) because it's not showing as the target field.  I will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find [Physical Field](http://drupal.org/project/physical) integration with [Commerce Feed](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) module for mapping your fields such as height, width or length, please have a look on a discussion started by bmx269 at http://drupal.org/node/1293820. Apply the patch & you will be able to find the field to map with your CSV file header.

Good luck...

Comment: Hi Rajeev, just bumped into this myself and I'm having a problem with the values not being imported correctly. All the mapping are there, but no data is imported. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[A patch was committed to the dev version](https://www.drupal.org/node/1372070) as of Nov. 26, 2016 (Drupal 7). If there is a release after that date it should be included, otherwise you'll need to use the dev version.